# Keep up in shape and muscle mass

Tags: maintenance

I'm 26 and |I used to workout a lot(every day). Now, I have school and need to spend a lot of times in front of a computer. Is there a way for me to keep up my shape and muscle mass(Like super sets for short period of time)? How fast will I lose muscles if I stop working out? Would eat a lot affect muscle mass(would I just gain fat and not lose muscle mass so that I can just burn them out later when I finish school)?

Comment: Your question suggests that you have some time for exercise. How long? In general it shouldn’t take more than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not training, no matter how well you eat... Your muscle is going to shrink. Without training it's impossible to maintain/build muscle mass because it's the process of breaking down the muscle tissue and rebuilding it.

> How fast will I lose muscles if I stop working out?

This depends on the person, everyone is different.

High intensity training with no more rest then necessary with lots of super sets is what you want to be doing if you have less time to train. Workouts should never be longer than an hour at max